# How to multithread a large sequence

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array

If it matters, I'm working in Unity with C#.

Anyways, I'm working on a 2D top-down game and, to simulate our water (and various other environmental hazards which have direct gameplay relevance), I use a large 2D grid that stores what hazard is in a given space. At an interval, I iterate through the grid and each space reacts to its 4 adjacent spaces. This process isn't problematically slow, but I dislike how it is all bound to one thread and takes up a good chunk of time whenever there's a large amount of hazards in the simulated area.

Problem is: I have no clue how to multi-thread a large amount of small calculations that directly rely on the state of adjacent data, nor do I know how to phrase this question to even google a good article on the subject.

Comment: Look at the new unity job system. You can use it separately and not need to do entities etc

Comment: I'm aware of the job system and understand regular multithreading, but when each entry in a 2D grid runs calculations involving the entries before, after, above, and below it - I don't understand how you can run the calculations for individual entries or groups on different threads without losing data / getting inconsistencies

Comment: Infalliblecode, and CodeMokey both have how to interact with jobs and monbehavior, codemonkeys maybe more applicable as he does a*  path finding and its a bit more like what you're doing you're just not finding a path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I ended up using to solve my problem was to break my large 2D array into chunks and run the sequential calculations (each piece being relevant to the pieces vertically and horizontally adjacent) for each chunk on a different thread, but left the edge-pieces of data alone (that would affect / be affected by the adjacent edge-pieces of other chunks). Upon finishing all chunks, I'd then iterate through the skipped parts on the main thread (or, in Unity's case, a single job with burst compilation for extra lovely speed) to form a cohesive whole.